# No enclosing instance of type mainframeclass is accessible

Tags: java, class, tags, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I get the error `No enclosing instance of type mainframeclass is accessible` when I try to compile/launch my program in Eclipse. Here is the code:

```
public class mainframeclass {

    public static Object mainframemenuitem1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainframe = new JFrame(variables.mainframename);

        mainframe.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        mainframe.setSize(variables.mainframewith, variables.mainframeheight);
        mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainframe.setVisible(variables.mainframevisible);
        mainframe.setResizable(variables.mainframeresizable);

        JMenuBar mainframemenubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu mainframemenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem mainframemenuitem1 = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mainframe.setJMenuBar(mainframemenubar);

        mainframemenubar.add(mainframemenu);
        mainframemenu.add(mainframemenuitem1);

        actionlistener listen = new actionlistener();
        mainframemenuitem1.addActionListener(listen);

        runningclass.running();
    }

    public class actionlistener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == mainframemenuitem1)
                System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that I have done something wrong with the:

```
actionlistener listen = new actionlistener();
```

but I don't know what. I am new to Java and would appreciate any insight into this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your `actionlistener` class (which should be renamed to follow Java naming conventions and with a more meaningful name) is an *inner class* (as opposed to a static nested class), which means it's only valid with an enclosing instance of `mainframeclass` to refer to... which it doesn't actually *need*, given that it refers to `mainframemenuitem1` which is static anyway.

So you *can* just change it to:

```
public static class actionlistener implements ActionListener
```

and it should work. Well, it will compile, anyway. It won't actually do what you want because you've got two `mainframemenuitem1` variables - the static one, and then a *local* one within your `main` method, so the static one never gets assigned a non-null value.

I would either pass `mainframemenuitem1` into the constructor of `actionlistener` and still make it a static nested class, or just make `mainframemenuitem1` final within the `main` method and create an anonymous inner class for the action listener.

Having said that:

> i am kinda new to java

In that case, I would actually stop with GUIs entirely for the moment. It's much simpler to learn about a new language without the complications introduced by GUIs. Writing console applications allows you to concentrate on learning just *one* thing at a time.